# Add Your Own Custom Namespace to the My Namespace in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, my-namespace

I know how to add methods to the MY namesapce, but what I'd like to do is create my own namespaces.  For example.  My.Nation.State.City.Restraunt or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531245.aspx) or [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/myextensions.aspx). I believe what you want would come under the "Adding Custom Objects to the My Namespace" umbrella.

Comment: Thanks.  The docs helped me figure out this was someting I didn't want to do and why.  Sometimes knowing what not to do is worth as much as knowing what to do.  I really appreciate the help.